# Разрешение зависимостей Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac, di

Создал текстовый проект консольный. Подтянул autofac. Собственно есть проект библиотеки с интерфейсами. Есть пара проектов библиотек, использующих эти интерфейсы. Каждая библиотека имеет класс модуля

```
namespace ClassLibrary2{

public class Class2Module : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
       builder.RegisterType<Class1>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
    }    
  }
}
```

где реализация такая

```
public class Class1 : INterface2
{
    public void PrintServiceData()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Данные класса 2");
    }
}
```

Таких реализаций 3 штуки.
Создана еще одна библиотека с реализациями вида

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
public class Application
{
    protected readonly INterface2 _nterface2;
    protected readonly INterface3 _nterface3;
    protected readonly INterface4 _nterface4;

    public Application(INterface2 nterface2, INterface3 nterface3, INterface4 nterface4)
    {
        _nterface2 = nterface2;
        _nterface3 = nterface3;
        _nterface4 = nterface4;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        _nterface2.PrintServiceData();
        _nterface3.PrintServiceData();
        _nterface4.PrintServiceData();
    }
}
}
```

И собственно вопрос. Все библиотеки зарегистрированы в контейнере, но при попытке запуска вылетает ошибка

> DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'ConsoleApp2.Application' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
>   Cannot resolve parameter 'ClassLibrary2.INterface2 nterface2' of constructor 'Void .ctor(ClassLibrary2.INterface2, ClassLibrary1.INterface3, ClassLibrary1.INterface4)'.

Что не так? Библиотеки регистрируются как пример с гитхаба динамически как

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterType<Application>().AsSelf();

var assemblies = Directory.GetFiles(path + "\\" + folder, "*.dll", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    .Select(Assembly.LoadFrom);

foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
{
    var modules = assembly.GetTypes()
        .Where(p => typeof(IModule).IsAssignableFrom(p) && !p.IsAbstract)
        .Select(p => (IModule) Activator.CreateInstance(p));

    foreach (var module in modules)
    {
        builder.RegisterModule(module);
    }
}
```

и судя по отладке нужные обьекты есть в контейнере.

---

[image: Отладка]

Нет, не резолвит. Хотя вот они в контейнере.

Comment: По отдельности каждый INterface2 резолвится?

Comment: Закинул на гитхаб. Может кто глянет и подскажет. https://github.com/Little-Cat/ConsoleApp2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть разница между получением сборок через `Assembly.LoadFrom` ([комментарий в оф.доках](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom?view=netframework-4.8#%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8)) и через `Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(INterface2))`. В первом случае сборка грузится только чтение. Поэтому `Autofac` не может зарезолвить ни один тип из нее, а в другом сборка ищется в [домене приложения](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.appdomain?view=netframework-4.8) (все сборки, которым можно доверять).

Собственно если ваши либы вообще никак не ссылались внутри текущего проекта задумку с динамическим подтягиванием можно было бы понять и сворганить что-нибудь такое:

```
var assemblies = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(path, folder), "*.dll", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    .Select(p => AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(new AssemblyName(Assembly.LoadFrom(p).FullName)))
    .ToArray();
builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(assemblies);
```

Но т.к. проекты лежат внутри, то лучше зарегистрировать их (проекты) ручками.

```
var assemblies = new[]
{
    Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(INterface2)), Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(INterface3)),
    Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(INterface4))
};
builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(assemblies);
```

Есть вариант достать все загруженные сборки из домена приложения, но это способ не гарантирует что в момент регистрации в нем будут все сборки, которые должны были попасть в контейнер. Сборка попадает в домен сразу же как JIT компилятор найдет первую ссылку на нее.

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Все получилось.